# SEO tools to determine audience size for search phrases

Tags: seo, local-seo

Are there any tools available that can indicate the search volume for a given set of phrases/keywords for a given location? For example, if I had a local pizza website that served only Manhattan and received 100 hits a day, how could I tell if this is roughly the expected throughput based on audience size or if my number are bad and I need to invest more on keyword analysis, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has a [traffic estimator associated with AdWords](https://adwords.google.com/select/KeywordToolExternal). Given that it's associated with AdWords, it might be stretching things a bit to assume you'd have the same results with organic search. And it's Google, not search in general.

Still, that's better than nothing.

It seems like Google used to have a different tool for this, but I couldn't find it in a quick search.